# Convert an array of logical type to an array of integer/double type

Tags: arrays, type-conversion, fortran, integer

I am using Silverfrost FTN95 and, since I am not an expert, I need your help to create a function which takes as input an array of logical variables and returns an array of integer variables, 0 for false and 1 for true.
I wrote this simple code just to semplify how I tried to implement it:

```
program main
logical, dimension(2,1)     :: a
integer, dimension(2,1)     :: b
integer, dimension(2,1)     :: toInt
a(:,1)=.false.
b=toInt(a)
write(*,*)b
end program

function toInt(log) result(val)
logical, dimension(2,1), intent(in)     :: log
integer, dimension(2,1)                 :: val
do i=1,2
    if (log(i,1)) then
        val(i,1) = 1
    else
        val(i,1) = 0
    end if
end do
end function
```

This code gives me this error: INTEGER expression expected in array bounds subscript, variable 'A' does not have the INTEGER type (at line "b=toInt(a)"), and I can't find what the error is.
Any suggestions or other ways to solve my problem would be very helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Always use `implicit none` before asking for help! Be sure to read why it is so dangerous not to use it. I could see some exceptions for old programs, but not here. I also suggest you to use modules wherever possible.

Comment: depending on the overall code, the most computationally efficient approach might be to not use the logical array at all. Replacing `if(a(i))` with `if(b(i).ne.0)` *probably* costs nothing except code convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message comes because in the program `main` you've declared `toint` to be an array, so the statement `toint(a)` is interpreted as an attempt to index into that array using the logical `a`.  You probably think that you've declared `toint` as an external function which returns an integer array, but you've not given the compiler enough information to make the connection with the function definition.

You could fix that by removing the misleading declaration of `toint` from the program, by moving the line `end program` to the end of your source file, and by inserting the line `contains` where you currently have `end program`.  These steps will make `toint` internal and the compiler will take care of matching your calls to the function itself.

But I think that there are 3, possibly more, better ways, than what you currently have.

One would be to write something along the lines of

```
integer, dimension(x,y) :: a,b,r
logical, dimension(x,y) :: m

! set the elements of m as you wish

a = 1
b = 0

r = merge(a,b,m)
```

which will assign to `r` the values from `a` where `m` is `.true.` and from `b` where `m` is `.false.` It doesn't matter what `x` and `y` are, just that the array arguments to `merge` are conformable. It should be relatively easy to turn this into a function for repeated use.

Secondly, you could use a `where` statement, perhaps like this

```
r = 0            ! all elements are set to 0
where(m) r = 1   ! where m is true, r is set to 1
```

This approach dispenses with `a` and `b`.

Thirdly you could investigate writing an `elemental` function which operates on scalars and on arrays of any rank. I'll leave this one as an exercise. It requires some modification to the function you already have, so that it operates on scalars and not on fixed-size arrays. This third approach is probably the best - most straightforward, most flexible, easiest to program.

Comment: Which of the three, in your opinion, is the most efficient in terms of computational time?

Answer (score 0):

Over and above Mark's 3 possibilities a 4th is the merge intrinsic function - actually this is essentially his 3rd suggestion, just that it is already in the language. Here's an example:

```
ian@ian-pc:~/test/stack$ cat merge.f90 
Program m

  Implicit None

  Logical, Dimension( 1:3, 1:2 ) :: log
  Integer, Dimension( 1:3, 1:2 ) :: val

  log = .False.
  log( 2, 1 ) = .True.

  val = Merge( 1, 0, log )

  Write( *, * ) val

End Program m
ian@ian-pc:~/test/stack$ nagfor -C=all -C=undefined merge.f90 
NAG Fortran Compiler Release 5.3.1(907)
[NAG Fortran Compiler normal termination]
ian@ian-pc:~/test/stack$ ./a.out
 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Actually, using `merge` was my first suggestion.  But my suggestion overlooked the much more straightforward use of scalars for the merge values that you illustrate here.